# Rewrite condition to remove specific parameter in Prestashop

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, prestashop-1.6

I have around 1000 categories created in prestashop and I have SPSEARCHPRO module installed. This module enables me to live search though my products.
Live search doesn't work due to the high number of categories but if I search normally it doesn't work either because the cat_id are included in the link and the link is too long. I suppose that's why the live search doesn't work either.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

I have this link:
https://example.com/en/module/spsearchpro/catesearch?fc=module&module=spsearchpro&controller=catesearch&orderby=name&orderway=desc&cat_id=2%2C4%2C(etc etc etc etc etc)

how can I remove the cat_id parameter from the link because the value is too long, it includes all the category id's.

I'm on prestashop 1.6.1.9 with multistore enabled (I don't know if that matters).

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with rewriting. If you have URLs that are too long, you need to prevent them from being in your output to begin with.

Comment: not possible...it's a module that receives updates...i must rewrite the URL instead...

Comment: You going to respond?

Answer (score 0):

Putting this early in your `.htaccess` should cut out the unwanted parameter when the path ends with the category search slug, you may need to add other slugs to that if there are more affected pages.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*?&)?cat_id=(?>[^&]*)(?:&(.*))?$
RewriteRule ^.*/catesearch$ /$0?%1%2 [NS,DPI,PT]
```

You may have to use `L,R` instead of `DPI,PT` flags if PrestaShop doesn't trust the `$_GET` it starts with (which comes from the rewritten URL). I'm unsure because it looks like it re-parses the URL from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` which is unchanged by rewriting and would overwrite the corrected parameters with the original undesired ones. It may be the only way to make it work is an external redirect.